# Jenkins: How to configure a always running server in a multijob scenario?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am new to jenkins and trying to configure a server-client scenario using Multijob plugin.

So here's how it should go :

Phase 1: Compilation of the code.
             In this one a separate project runs in which only compilation shell command is given

Phase 2: Running of Server 
             In this one a shell command project is given to run the server

Phase3 : Running of Client 
             In this one the client command should run

**PROBLEM FACED** : The project gets paused as the phase 2 never ends (with fail or success). As the server is always running one.

I tried giving the running of client parallel in phase 2 as a diff job but with that sometimes client job starts running before server job. Moreover I have multiple client jobs so it would be wise to create a different phase for them.

Can somebody please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As phase 2 runs a shell command, I assume the server is running on Linux.  Put an ampersand character after the server run command to put the process in background:

```
run_server &
```

and phase 2 will complete as soon as the server is launched.  You'll probably also want to send the server's console output to a file, e.g.

```
run_server > server.log 2>&1 &
```

(the 2>&1 sends stdout and stderr output to the same file)

Comment: Hello gareth, I ran into a bit of trouble using & .. actually my server takes a command line port number as : server_run -p #number

If i give & at the end it starts running at 19665 automatically. ignoring the number I gave

Comment: Also i checked running the job with & in the backend ! It worked fine .. Like the server is listening at designated port number . But when I try giving it from the Jenkins shell command, it is creating some weird issue.